# Three.js scuffed rendering

Tags: oop, three.js, rendering

I have an 3D cube, I was implementing outlining objects upon hovering over them, when I created the meshes within the project it worked fine (basic meshes like cube etc.), but when I imported the tree model in gltf format, after I added it to the scene the outlining broke and it is behaving weirdly, I'm rendering only one tree (random from 5 different trees), but after I hover over the tree to outline it, the tree disappears and another type of tree appears and is highlighted, any ideas why it could be happening?

My pieces of code:

```
  constructor({ canvas }: { canvas: HTMLCanvasElement }) {
    this.renderer = new WebGLRenderer({ canvas, antialias: true, logarithmicDepthBuffer: true })
    this.composer = new EffectComposer(this.renderer)
    this.outlinePass = new OutlinePass(new Vector2(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight), this.scene, this.camera)
    this.outlinePass.visibleEdgeColor = new Color('yellow')

    const renderPass = new RenderPass(this.scene, this.camera)
    this.composer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
    this.composer.addPass(renderPass)
    this.composer.addPass(this.outlinePass)

    window.addEventListener('mousemove', this.onMouseMove)
  }

  onMouseMove = (e: any) => {
    this.raycaster.setFromCamera({
      x: (e.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1,
      y: -(e.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1
    }, this.camera)

    const intersects = this.raycaster.intersectObjects(this.group.children, true)

    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
      var object = intersects[0].object
      while (object.parent && !object.userData.outline) object = object.parent

      this.outlinePass.selectedObjects = [object]
    } else this.outlinePass.selectedObjects = []
  }

  draw = () => {
    this.animation = requestAnimationFrame(() => this.draw())
    
    this.composer.render()
    this.arrayOfObjects.forEach(object => object.draw())
  }

  treeRender = () => {
    this.loader.load(treeModelPaths[getRandomTreeIndex()], (gltf) => {
      const scene = gltf.scene

      this.group.add(scene)
    })
  }
```

Here are some important links:
[GIF with weird behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbR7B.gif)

[Repository to full code](https://github.com/Entita/cubic_world)

I found out, that when I remove the outling ('OutlinePass') the projects works fine, it renders only one tree, which is behaving correctly, that makes me wonder if the 'RenderPass' is working properly, which I'm using to render the scene.

EDIT:
Surprisingly enough, on production (and on the stackblitz) it is rendering and working properly.

[Production link](https://cubic-world.vercel.app/)

[Stackblitz - simplified example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/threejs-cdn-bskban?file=index.html)

Comment: Surprisingly enough, on production it is rendering and working properly ... weird. https://cubic-world.vercel.app

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with a smaller example? Preferably one that can be contained completely within the question. Also, try to embed all relevant information (code, images) in the question because when (not if) the links go bad, your question will lose important context for future readers.

Comment: I reproduced the same set up as I have in my project in this small example, but it's working properly here, like on my production, that's what I don't get. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/threejs-cdn-bskban?file=index.html

Comment: So the question becomes: What is different between your dev and prod environments? Is your dev running raw code, and your production running bundled code? An example of the difference might be that, while [JavaScript supports ASI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#automatic_semicolon_insertion), your bundler may be physically adding them, and it's making a difference in your code execution.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know much about that, all I can say is on dev I'm using next.js with default settings and on production vercel with default settings.

Comment: You were right, the code was running twice, because of the option "reactStrictMode" in my next.config.js file on development. Thank you, can you write something similar as your last message as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hidden question here is actually: What is different between your dev and prod environments?

Your development and production environments must be executing the code differently, either from something you do (or don't do) to the code, or maybe from a side-effect from another library.

For example, if your dev environment is running raw code, and your production is running bundled code, then the bundler could be doing something that is making your code actually work. (An example of the difference might be that, while [JavaScript supports ASI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#automatic_semicolon_insertion), your bundler may be physically adding semicolons to its output, and it's making a difference in your code execution.)

So, double-check how your code is executed in each environment. If there's no difference in the code in both places, start looking at wrappers, frameworks, and other libraries for conflicts.